# Is the compiler able to optimize spaghetti code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am writing a compiler that generates C++ code at the end, I can't use `while\for` or any other normal loop so I translate it to `goto\if` and assigments\call lines like this:

```
if (i<b) goto loop_959__again;
loop_959__end: ;
}
{
int inumber;
int i;
i=0;
inumber=3;
if (!(inumber<30)) goto loop_4482__end;
loop_4482__again:
float fnumber;
_A1__main__increase(__owner);
i++;
inumber++;
fnumber=3;
loop_4482__step_begin:
if (inumber<30) goto loop_4482__again;
loop_4482__end: ;
}
```

This is really painful to watch, but can GCC compiler compile and optimize code like the one above as if it consisted of normal loops and etc?

Comment: Sure it can, I only hope that is never going to be read from human eye

Comment: @MarcoA. I think I might going to look at this code when I have bug in the code generation. :'( But there's source to this? It's really important for this project. Or this is too trivial to having source? I tried to think about a way to like check it, but confused.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your previous statement

Comment: Check it. Compile it with and without optimization flags and check is assembler code is shorter in optimized compilation.

Comment: Why guess? Compile it to assembly (with appropriate optimization options turned on), and examine the assembly code.

Comment: @MarcoA. When I will have bug in the code generation (that generates this code) I will have to look at that code.

Comment: @Jepessen How I know it's exactly as it needs to be?

Comment: Looking at this awful C code I really wonder: are there any benefits from it being C? LLVM bit-code might be the right thing for you.

Comment: I recall MSVC tripping on something like 32768 goto's in a single function. That's a fairly arbitrary restriction for MSVC, as x86 assembly doesn't have that problem, but some other CPU's do!

Comment: @Alex I don't have academic eduaction at all, I really seek starting point to learn LLVM.

Comment: @MSalters Why CPU would have problem with more than 2^15 gotos? Really curious.

Comment: @KugBuBu http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html llvm has awesome documentation. it looks like the more suitable abstraction for you. it's a bit like an abstract assembler.

Comment: 1) studying assembler and checking that the code is the minimal one that does what you want 2) checking if in optimized mode the compiler produces less asm code. This means that someway compiler has optimized it.

Comment: @KugBuBu: Many CPU's have IP-relative jump instructions in which the offset is encoded in a few bits of the instruction. That means you can't jump to any random address directly. There are generally alternative implementations for "far jumps", e.g. by jumping to some kind of trampoline, but even then the trampoline must be reachable. If you have 32K trampolines, you might need 17 or 18 bits offset to jump to the last trampoline.

Comment: From practical experience with a compiler from a DSL to C, generating normal constructs like for and while loops instead of your own gotos can dramatically improve performance of the compiled code. I don't know if this was because the C compiler could analyze the code better or because I improved other things in the process, but just making the resulting code readable (the main goal was to improve human debuggability) cut down execution time of some benchmarks by up to 80%. Of course, YMMV.

Comment: @Art I did it too, I generated code from `while(true) {}` from my code generator (with gotos) and compared performance against `while (true) {}` and my generated code beat it. (Faster by 300%, like 4 times less instructions)

Comment: Looks more like Rotini to me.

Comment: @Alex Reminds me of .NET's IL, I think I will try to do some tests with it.

Comment: @MSalters You meant if the code is too long then you can't make far jumps. It's not directly my problem, you can make 100000-lines loop in my programming language, and in C too. (It won't differ or reduce the problem)

Comment: @KugBuBu: The problem is specifically if a function is too long. And no, you can't assume that all C compilers support 100.000 line loops.

Comment: @MSalters My code generator doesn't make the assembly longer (Look answer) every-line here can be translated to 0-2 lines of assembly instructions. (For example this 19-lines code can be translated to 17 instructions BEFORE optimizations) I am pretty good here I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compilers optimize program control flow with flow graphs analysis, using a `goto` instead of an `if` branch at that level is practically equivalent from a compiler's standpoint.

A caveat to keep in mind: since `gotos` can jump around practically everywhere in your function, if your generator generates [irreducible control flow graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph), that might definitely affect the compiler's optimization capabilities.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that `goto`s can make the question of whether or not a particular line is executed undecidable. Am I just wrong?

Comment: About the `irreducible control flow graphs` where I can get an example? That would help what not to do.

Comment: @KugBuBu in any compiler's construction book or by googling for lectures. I also recommend taking a look at LLVM's source code if you're interested in the matter (search for CFG analysis modules)

Comment: @MarcoA. Never mind, I found one in the actual article, sorry.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I recall of a paper somewhere, perhaps at saarland.de (http://www.cdl.uni-saarland.de/publications/) that studied the issue in depth. I'll see if I can find it