# Can using char[] as parameters, return, and etc do any performance issues?

Tags: c++, gcc

First to make the C++ code more readable; I am programming compiler, and I gave it:

```
var swap = ( int x, y ) => { //Assign method that returns two ints, and gets two ints as parameter to variable named swap.
    var NewX = y
    var NewY = x
}
var increment = ( int x ) => {
    var Result = x + 1
}
```

NOTE: Functions return any variable that it's first letter is capitalized. `swap` can be used like `... = swap( x, y ).NewX`, but `increment` can be used as just `... = increment( x )`.

After some optimization it generated: (Made `swap` and `increment` actual function instead of variables, and optimized `swap`'s stack)

```
template<int BytesCount> struct rawdata { //struct from some header
    char _[ BytesCount ];
    inline char &operator[] (int index) {
        return _[ index ];
    }
};

//...

rawdata<8> generatedfunction0( rawdata<8> p ) { // var swap = ( int x, y ) => {
    return{ p[ 4 ], p[ 5 ], p[ 6 ], p[ 7 ], p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] };
}
rawdata<4> generatedfunction1( rawdata<4> p ) { // var increment = ( int x ) => {
    rawdata<4> r = { p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] };
    ++*( ( int* )&r[ 0 ] );
    return r;
}
```

I am almost sure that `++*( ( int* )&r[ 0 ] );` won't do useless indirection, but how about `return{ p[ 4 ], p[ 5 ], p[ 6 ], p[ 7 ], p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] };`? Is there any source that guarantees that it will optimized it as if it was two ints that being put into array instead of 8 or more instructions that put byte by byte? I am not talking about this particular case only, but anything similar.

If it depends, then I am using GCC to compile the generated code.

Comment: There are very few guarantees when it comes to what code a compiler will generate after optimization. In this case, no, there's no guarantee of how it will fill the memory array, and I would be surprised if it did anything better than a byte-by-byte fill here.

Comment: @JasonR In this particular case it optimized it like it knew the result. (I tried to do `printf` and etc.) If you want to see similar example [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378197/is-the-compiler-able-to-optimize-spaghetti-code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can harm performances - but not always. The problem is in the explicit access of the individual bytes.

An "intelligent" compiler would recognise that you access contiguous memory and try to optimize it. However for some reason that doesn't work at all with gcc, clang or icc (haven't test msvc). There is still room for improvement for compiler optimizers, and IIRC the standard does not mandate any optimization.

**Swap**:

So, let's process each function, starting with swap. I added 2 more functions for completeness, see after the code snippet:

```
#include <stdint.h>

rawdata<8> genSWAP(rawdata<8> p)
{
    return { p[ 4 ], p[ 5 ], p[ 6 ], p[ 7 ], p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] };
}

rawdata<8> genSWAPvar(rawdata<8> p)
{
    return { p._[ 4 ], p._[ 5 ], p._[ 6 ], p._[ 7 ], p._[ 0 ], p._[ 1 ], p._[ 2 ], p._[ 3 ] };
}

rawdata<8> genSWAP32(rawdata<8> p)
{
    rawdata<8> res = p;
    uint32_t* a = (uint32_t*)&res[0];
    uint32_t* b = (uint32_t*)&res[4];
    uint32_t tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
    return res;
}
```

- `genSWAP` : your function
- `genSWAPvar` : the same as yours but without using the `operator[]` you defined
- `genSWAP32` : explicitely packing your bytes 32 bits per 32 bits

You can view [the generated asm here](http://goo.gl/ZaOwY4).

`genSWAP` and `genSWAPvar` are no different, meaning that the overloaded `operator[]` is just optimized out. However each byte is accessed in memory individually, and also processed individually. This is bad since on 32 bit architectures the processor load 4 bytes at once from memory (8 for 64 bit architectures). So in short gcc/clang/icc are emitting instructions to counter the real possibilities of 32bits architectures...

`genSWAP32` is way more efficient, doing the minimum number of loads (for 32bits), and correctly using the registers (note that for 64bits architectures it should be possible to do only one load instead of 2).

And finally, [some real measures](http://ideone.com/2VqeMJ): on Ideone `genSWAP32` is almost 4x faster (which make sense, because it has 2 loads instead of 8 and less computing instructions).

**Increment**:

Same here, your function vs "optimized" one:

```
rawdata<4> genINC(rawdata<4> p)
{
    rawdata<4> r = { p[ 0 ], p[ 1 ], p[ 2 ], p[ 3 ] };
    ++*( ( int* )&r[ 0 ] );
    return r;
}

rawdata<4> genINC32(rawdata<4> p)
{
    rawdata<4> res = p;
    uint32_t* a = (uint32_t*)&res[0];
    ++*a;
    return res;
}
```

The [generated asm is here](http://goo.gl/qGhLMe).

For clang and icc, the killer is not the increment but the initialization, where you access each byte individually. gcc and icc probably do this by default because the order of bytes could be different that `0 1 2 3`. Surprisingly, clang recognize that the order of bytes and optimizes this correctly - no perf difference.

Then something interesting happens: the `genINC32` function [is slower on gcc](http://ideone.com/fmwcRW), but faster on msvc (*I don't see a permalink button on rise4fun, so [go there](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and paste the code tested on ideone). Without seeing the msvc generated assembler and comparing I have no explanation for that.

**In conclusion**, while it is possible to have a compiler correctly optimize all your code, don't rely on that now, so don't access every byte individually if not needed.

Comment: Replying to your "In conclusion" in the end. I can't use `int`s and etc because the layer before the code generation won't let me guess what are the sizes of the object it passing. (Bad design maybe) I think I will just implement some optimization at the code generation layer to group bytes into `int` and etc. Thanks for your research, it helped me find new ways.